# Tensorflow Dataset - dataset.repeat()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    # Shuffle and repeat if you are in training mode.
    if training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()
    
    return dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

guys if the repeat() reinitalize the dataset infinitely how is that possible to break that loop to carry forward????
Like it will keep drawing from the dataset infinitely right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are "injecting" that as input to train your model, you will stop fetching data based on the training criteria of your model. It could be based on number of epochs, accuracy, etc.

Comment: hey CrazyBrazilian thanks!! aah maybe because i have the code ```DNNclassifier.train(steps = 5000)``` right??                     steps is No of times it is training right? since steps = 5000 why cant we specify ```repeat(5000)``` then?

Comment: Yes, steps is the number of steps which you will use to train the model. You could either stop based on the steps=xyz, or you don't specify that and the train will stop once all data has been consumed. So, yes, you could just use the repeat(5000) and then remove the steps=5000